# ICMP is not getting disabled

Tags: networking, systemd, ping, systemd-networkd

I am trying to disable ICMP services. For this the following configuration lines have been added into the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0
```

After these changes the command `sudo sysctl -p` is executed. After this I execute the command `cat cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` and the output that I get is `1`. Post this no ping requests are responded back. For example the following commands `ping localhost` results in the output

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- localhost ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3071ms
```

However the problem starts when I reboot or shutdown -- restart. After the desktop boots up the value of the parameter `icmp_echo_ignore_all` changes to 0(numerical zero). The output of the command `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`
 is 0 (numerical zero). I can ping the desktop from across my network and also ping using localhost.

So how do I resolve this issue? How do I get to stop the ICMP services? Is there something extra that I have to do to get the configuration specified in `/etc/sysctl.conf` in getting picked up?
My OS is xbuntu 16.04.6 LTS running on kernel 4.15.0-65-generic

Comment: Any help guys or guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when using UFW and eventually by chance found that `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all` is explicitly set to zero in `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`, apparently overriding the setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Updating the offending line in `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf` resolved the problem.